# Множественные запросы к Google через cURL

Tags: curl, php-curl

Нужно сделать несколько сотен запросов через сервисы google (не API). Но Google устанавливает ограничения на количество в секунду и определенный промежуток времени (100 запросов), исчерпав которые он перенаправляет на капчу. 
У меня идут запросы с интервалом в 1-5 секунд. После 100 запроса получаю 302 Moved ответ (на капчу). При этом, если после этого в браузере переходить по этим же запросам, то все открывается. Пытался подставлять заголовки, которые идут в браузере - не помогает.
Можно ли как-то это обойти?

Comment: Как вариант, при получении "302 Moved" делайте прогрессивную задержку (1,2,4,8,16,..max) секунд. При 200 ОК - сбрасывайте задержку на начальное значение. Какие заголовки подставляли? User-Agent пробовали менять?

Comment: User-Agent менял - не помогает. Заголовки стоят стандартные браузерные. Может ему куки какие-то нужно подкидывать?
После выдачи  "302 Moved" на капчу, нужно ждать пару часов, пока разблокирует

Comment: А в самом URL не пробовали что-то незначительно менять, к примеру ,что-то безобидное в параметры добавлять? Полагаю, они так защищаются от роботов сканеров или DDOS и обойти будет проблематично. Когда тестировали из браузера, там капча не появлялась даже если "F5-чить" раз в секунду больше 100 раз ?